# org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?

Tags: javers

We are trying to get javers 2.2.2 setup using Oracle and a Hibernate/JPA (non-spring) based App.

When using the internal repo and a standard (non-transactional) builder I am able to successfully log and retrieve audit objects. However, when I do a save after switching to the Transaction Builder w/ SQL I get the below stack trace. If it matters, we are indeed doing the Hibernate Access Hook.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type adapter?
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:76)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$1.write(TypeAdapters.java:69)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.write(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:652)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:545)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:524)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$2.serialize(Gson.java:137)
    at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotStateTypeAdapter.toJson(CdoSnapshotStateTypeAdapter.java:31)
    at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.CdoSnapshotStateTypeAdapter.toJson(CdoSnapshotStateTypeAdapter.java:14)
    at org.javers.core.json.JsonConverterBuilder$1.serialize(JsonConverterBuilder.java:124)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:63)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:652)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:631)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:586)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:566)
    at org.javers.core.json.JsonConverter.toJson(JsonConverter.java:55)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.repositories.CdoSnapshotRepository.insertSnapshot(CdoSnapshotRepository.java:37)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.repositories.CdoSnapshotRepository.save(CdoSnapshotRepository.java:27)
    at org.javers.repository.sql.JaversSqlRepository.persist(JaversSqlRepository.java:63)
    at org.javers.repository.api.JaversExtendedRepository.persist(JaversExtendedRepository.java:109)
    at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:79)
    at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:64)
    at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.commit(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:53)`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to commit `HibernateProxy`. In runtime, Hibernate wraps your domain objects and collections in proxy objects, mainly for lazy loading. So your domain objects become somehow *dirty*.
You have to unwrap them before committing to javers.

Javers provides dedicated hook for that - `HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook`:

```
TransactionalJaversBuilder
    .javers().withObjectAccessHook(new HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook()).build()
```

See http://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#hibernate-unproxy-hook for more detais

Comment: Hello Bartek, let me ask you, do you know if this should work also with non-spring applications?

Comment: yes, HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook should work without Spring

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing through **ObjectMapper** as

```
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myClass);
```